# Photobucket API python oAuth error

Tags: python, oauth, photobucket

I need to upload images to Photobucket using the API wrapper for Python.  I can get the request_token and request_token_secret but not the final access_token and access_token_secret. Instead, I get the following error message:

pbapi.error.PbApiError: (): Token and Token Secret not in response

The response I get is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
    <status>Exception</status>
    <message>Authentication failed no token</message>
    <code>7</code>
    <format>xml</format>
    <method>POST</method>
    <timestamp>1355787388</timestamp>
</response>
<!-- phx1api05 @ Mon, 17 Dec 2012 16:36:28 -0700 -->
```

Here is my code:

```
api = pbapi.PbApi(API_KEY, API_SECRET)
api.pb_request.connection.cache = None

# Getting request token
api.reset().login().request().post().load_token_from_response()

# Requesting user permission (you have to login with your account)
webbrowser.open_new_tab(api.login_url)
raw_input("Press Enter when you finished access permission. ")

#Getting oAuth token
#api.reset().login().access().post().load_token_from_response()
print api.reset().login().access().post().response_string
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Photobucket is an extremely difficult provider because of the way they redirect endpoints. However I'm a little surprised their own wrapper doesn't work. I would recommend [rauth](https://github.com/litl/rauth) but it won't work out of the box: you'd have to subclass the signature object which manually overloads the URL to sign, i.e. setting it to `'api.photobucket.com'` and then pass your custom signature object into the session constructor. It's doable but a tad bit messy. I have this working for a project at work, but I don't have an example I can provide for you right now.